# TCP connections hang during handshake

Tags: tcp, nat

For the last few days, connections originating behind my LAN's NAT have been having issues completing the TCP handshake (i.e. web pages only load after hitting F5 a few times, network applications sometimes timeout when starting, etc.). After a TCP connection is estabilished, everything works fine.

My network configuration is ~20 machines behind an EdgeOS router, which masquerades internal addresses to my ISP's PPPoE endpoint. No updates or configuration changes have been made recently (last 6 months at least). I've excluded NAT port exhaustion, memory exhaustion and my ISP doesn't run CGNAT. The issue presents both on Windows and Linux machines, which means the culprit is most probably the ISP.

The issue at hand is, how do I investigate and document such a problem on my side?

Answer (score 8):

You state that TCP connections run fine once they get established. That makes a cause on the ISP's network unlikely: ISP routers are usually stateless, so they don't care for layers above the network (IP) layer, and (random) packet loss would impact all packets alike, during and after establishing a connection.

More likely, your NAT router fails to establish new NAT sessions. This may be due to port exhaustion, memory exhaustion or some other system limitation. You should check the router for logged errors and warnings, memory or other resource exhaustion or such.

If router diagnosis doesn't locate the problem you might need to run a packet capture on your NAT router's WAN interface to make sure that TCP SYNs etc. make it across the router. You can also compare that capture to one made on an outside, known-good host. If you're sure that packets make it across your router and don't make it to the ultimate destination, then your ISP needs to answer some questions.

Comment: While you have a (very, very) fair point, I did not change anything in the network configuration & I have restarted the router multiple times, and the problem presents immediately after a reboot, which means resource (port, memory, etc.) exhaustion is unlikely. I will do a very simple test this evening: I'm going to route traffic through a different ISP from the same router. If that fails to identify the culprit, I'm going to run the other tests you suggested.

Comment: @rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr Nothing in the logs?

Comment: Nope, nothing of interest.

Comment: That first paragraph would only hold if the ISP is not applying CGNAT, right? If this is a new development then that's possibly something that has changed on the ISP end. Of course, if @rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr is on a business plan that's unlikely - CGNAT is usually residential/consumer only, barring a mixup on the ISP side.

Comment: @bob Absolutely - however even then, resources for *carrier-grade* NAT should be ample and never run out.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify - no CGNAT. In fact, I have multiple IP addresses the router uses for masquerading, one of which is especially dedicated to my personal workstation, so it should _never_ run out.

Comment: Anyway, the issue seems to have gone away with no action on my part, so maybe it _was_ the ISP after all. Which definitely brings up the question of why would they distinguish between different types of TCP packets. Could it be a (very stupid) form of traffic shaping? A temporary measure to fix something?

Comment: @rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr Could be anything really. However, guessing and speculating are explicitly off-topic here...

Comment: Then we're out of work!

Comment: @rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr Guessing and speculating are off-topic *here on NESE* - definitely not in your daily routine... :-P